# Mount ATA drives on directory named after UUID

Tags: debian, automounting

I need a way to automatically mount **ATA** and **SCSI** drive partitions on directories named for their UUIDs (e.g., `/media/1234-ABCD`) on a **Debian jessie** system *without having to log in*.

Since the drives are always changing, hard coding the mount in `/etc/fstab` is not feasible.

What would be the most effective way to accomplish this? Is it even possible in Debian jessie?

Comment: You could have a look at the package `usbmount`, which will do something similar for USB drives triggered by `udevd`. Would, of course, need some modification in `/lib/udev/rules.d/usbmount.rules` and `/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount` to react not only on USB drives and to mount them regardless if there are entries in `fstab` or not.